# Microservice response timing for same calls

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

Just want to know if we have any pattern to use to solve the problem which i have faced.
I have a menu bar with multiple menus - On click of each item, my service A will be invoked and will return the data for a table.

Now the problem is
At time t, menu item 1 clicked, and service A invoked - awaiting the response.
At time t+1, menu item 2 clicked and service A invoked - got the response immediately.
At time t+2, response of service invocation at time t returned response.

The end result is menu item 2 selected and data of menu item 1 is shown because its override the table data with more recent response.

Please can someone suggest any solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Disable menu items which would cause conflicting results until the response has been displayed.